# How can I make div width fill the rest of the page?

Tags: html, css

It sounds easy but I'm going crazy figuring this out.

So I have a an 'App.jsx' file which has sidebar, and this sidebar is fixed.
So to have this sidebar with other components and pages I added `display: flex` to 'App.css`;

And so I have a `Home` page. And my `home_container` class looks like this:

```
.home_container {
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

What it looks like on the page:
[image]

I want it to fill the rest of the page, but it only fills half of it with `width: 100%`.
I tried `width:100vw` but then it just goes outside of the page and I have an overflow.

I want to figure out how can I fill this div to the end without overflow.

Edit:
parent div is `App` and it only has one style:

```
.App{
  display: flex;
}
```

And also `NavBar`:

```
.nav_bar{
    height:100vh;
    width: 75px;
    background-color:#2e2e2e;
}
```

What the structure looks like:

[image]

What `App.jsx` looks like:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
        <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<PrivateRoute><Home/></PrivateRoute>}/>
          <Route exact path="/profile" element={<PrivateRoute><Profile/></PrivateRoute>}/>
        </Routes>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please share the whole code to be able to find out if you have set the parent div a particular width or not

Comment: @SumitSharma hi! i edited my orginal question

Comment: I am guessing that your home container is a child of another element. To fix it either get it out of it or else make the position absolute and not relative.

Comment: @ArchitGargi it's a child of an `App.jsx`, cause it's one of the pages. so position absolute is a solution&

Comment: Uh so ur problem is solved then?

Comment: You'd be better off updating your question with enough detail to let people answer instead of having people guess what you didn't show them..

Comment: @svin83 you're right, i'll add some more details, thanks

Comment: okay, i added some more details, i hope the picture is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: relative` to `position: absolute` to solve the problem.